# $.ajax POST Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in MVC5

Tags: javascript

i am trying this code

```
function updateProperty() {

    var OR_ID = localStorage.getItem("OR_ID");
    var ORObject_Id = localStorage.getItem("ORObject_Id");

    var ORObjectProperty = JSON.stringify(ObjectPropertiesData)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "Html",
        url: "/ObjectRepository/ORObjectPropertySave",
        data: { OR_ID: OR_ID, ORObject_Id: ORObject_Id, PropertyData: ORObjectProperty },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('success update')

        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            var err = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);
            Message("Error", err.message);
        }
    });

}


JSON.stringify(ObjectPropertiesData)


var ObjectPropertiesData= function (ObjectProperty, State) {
    this.ObjectProperty = ObjectProperty;
    this.State = State;
}

var ObjectProperty = function (Property_ID, PropertyName, DataType, IsUsed,IsRegex, Value) {
    this.Property_ID = Property_ID;
    this.PropertyName = PropertyName;
    this.DataType = DataType;
    this.IsUsed = IsUsed;
    this.IsRegex = IsRegex;
    this.Value = Value;
}
```

the Problem is that sometimes is working well but sometime its througt exception-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) And

Index:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: The 404 sends an HTML page starting with <DOCTYPE or <HTML - that is the error you see. Do not try to parse the error as JSON. Your issue here is the 404 only and not the error message

Comment: thanx for your help please mark this as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is the 404 only and not the error message

The 404 sends an HTML page starting with

Do not try to parse the error as JSON.